# Why does my function return "undefined" but works with console.log please ? How to solve that please?

Tags: node.js, callback, undefined, node-postgres

I have a problem to make working my token validation function in nodeJS. My "return" always returns "undefined" ... But the console.log works.
This function's utility is to validate a JWT Token, comparing token information with my database for the id and admin tag :

```
const verifyTokenValidity = (token) => {
  try{
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, 'JWT_PASS_SECRET')
    const checkTokenIdentity_query = sql = fs.readFileSync('./sqlquery/checkTokenIdentity_query.sql').toString()
    const tok_account_id = decodedToken.account_id
    const tok_is_admin = decodedToken.isadmin
    pool.query(checkTokenIdentity_query, [tok_account_id], (error, results) => {
      const bdd_account_id = String(JSON.stringify(results.rows[0].ac_account_id)).replace(/['"]+/g, '')
      const bdd_is_admin = String(JSON.stringify(results.rows[0].ac_isadmin)).replace(/['"]+/g, '')
      if (tok_account_id == bdd_account_id || tok_is_admin == bdd_is_admin){
        return 'valid'
      }
      else {
        return 'invalid'
      }
    })

  }
  catch(error) {
    return 'invalid' 
  }
}
```

When I execute the function with a valid token :

```
console.log(verifyTokenValidity('ayJhbG.........iaXNhZG1pbiI6ImZhbHNlIiwi......TkzLCJleHAiOjE2MTYxODgzOTN9......JT0PhXCjV00'))
>>>>> undefined
```

If I replace all the occurences of return by console.log I have a "valid" result.
I think there is a callback problem but after a lot of research and test I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Thanx for helping me,

F4nch.

Comment: `verifyTokenValidity` doesn’t return anything in the `try` branch. The two `return`s inside the `pool.query` callback don’t return anywhere.

Comment: The function needed to be async that is why it did not worked.